# MDX query total sell price of rows with more than 10 quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I need to have a total sell price of rows that have more than 10 Quantity.

The result of the following query is the total sell price.

```
SELECT {[Sell Price]} ON COLUMNS
FROM SALES
```

I have to filter the above query with the condition ([Sell Quantity] > 10) for bellow dimensions.

```
[Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name]
[Goods].[Goods Name].[Goods Name]
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** 
Example data is like bellow

```
Customer       Goods       Quantity     Price
-------------------------------------------------
A              X            2            1000
B              X            15           2000
C              Y            20           3000
C              X            3            6000
```

Customers and Goods are dimensions. I need a total price of second and third rows because quantity of these rows is more than 10.

My expected result is **5000**.

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular form and schema as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use filter function. Based on the schema shared above your query will be

```
Select 
{
[Sell Price]
}on columns 
from yourCube
where 
{filter(
    ([Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name],[Goods].[Goods Name].[Goods Name]),
    [Sell Quantity] > 10)}
```